# Add callback to this function Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add this function fadeInBoxes();   as a callback to this click function. I cant get the syntax right for the life of me. So after all of this does its job, I want to load my function above. any ideas?

```
$(".select").click(function(){
     fadeBoxes();
     var num = $(this).attr('rel');
     $("ul").roundabout("animateToChild", num);
     chageDots(num);
  });
```

Full Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     function chageDots(dot){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           $("#dot0"+i).removeClass("active");

        };
        $("#dot0"+dot).addClass("active");
     };

     var images = ["img1.jpg","img1.jpg","img1.jpg","img1.jpg","img1.jpg"];

     for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        $("#img0"+j).css("background-image","url('"+images[j]+"')");
        $("#img0"+j).css("background-size","cover");
     };

     var fade_start=false;
     chageDots(0);

    $('ul').roundabout({          
        btnNext: '.next',          
        btnPrev: '.back',
        btnNextCallback: function() {
           var data = $(this).data("roundabout");
           var current_num = data.childInFocus;
           chageDots(current_num);
           fadeInBoxes();
        },
        btnPrevCallback: function() {
           var data = $(this).data("roundabout");
           var current_num = data.childInFocus;
           chageDots(current_num);
           fadeInBoxes();
        },
        clickToFocusCallback: function(){
           var data = $(this).data("roundabout");
           var current_num = data.childInFocus;
           chageDots(current_num);
           current_num.click == false;
           fadeInBoxes();
        }
     }); 

  $(".next").click(function() {
     fadeBoxes();
  });
  $(".back").click(function() {
     fadeBoxes();
  });
  $("li").click(function() {
     fadeBoxes();
  });

  $(".select").click(function(){
     fadeBoxes();
     var num = $(this).attr('rel');
     $("ul").roundabout("animateToChild", num);
     chageDots(num);

  });



  function fadeBoxes (){
     if(fade_start != true){
        fade_start = true;
        $("#mainBox").fadeOut("fast",function() {
         // Animation complete.
         fade_start = false;
        });
        $("#leftBox").fadeOut("fast",function() {
         // Animation complete.
         fade_start = false;
        });
        $("#rightBox").fadeOut("fast",function() {
         // Animation complete.
         fade_start = false;
        });
     } 
  };
  function fadeInBoxes (){
     $("#mainBox").fadeIn(200);
     $("#leftBox").fadeIn(100);
     $("#rightBox").fadeIn(100);
  };
```

});

Comment: Do `roundabout()` or `chageDot()` take a callback themselves?

Comment: yes, they do. I added full code here, its messy but if it helps...

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it's confusing in it's present form.  If you need fadeBoxes as a simple click handler callback.. its:  $(".select").click(fadeBoxes)

Comment: why is it confusing, I want to add a callback function after my click function finishes..

Answer (score 0):

Look for this: [jquery click callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394938/jquery-click-callback)
Pioul says: The click event is triggered immediately, and has a duration of 0, thus it doesn't have any callback.

Comment: This kind of helped me, but I figured out my problem, I added the function after my num var in $("ul").roundabout("animateToChild", num, fadeInBoxes);